# how to read all "Map" name and associate "Role"

Tags: c#, configuration

I have a config file like below,

```html
<Hello>
  <Maps>
    <Map name="X1">
      <Roles>
        <Role name="Y1" />
      </Roles>
    </Map>
    <Map name="X2">
      <Roles>
        <Role name="Y2" />
      </Roles>
    </Map>
  </Maps>
</Hello>
```

Now I want to loop through all the "Map" (X1, X2), but below line of code giving me only one map X2, how to get both,

```
 var a = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link may help:

[XML reading child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920082/xml-reading-child-nodes)

You need to have a for-each loop as one of the answers in the link.